# Excel VBA code to find, store and retrieve data from the most recently changed cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a code that finds the most recently changed cell in Sheet1 (range B4:B4003), stores it as a variable ("reprint") and can then paste that information into a cell in Sheet2 as a separate module. So I would need two lines of code, one to find and store the information and another to retrieve and paste it. Or perhaps I'm barking up the wrong tree entirely! Appreciate any ideas on how I could do this.

Current code to store most recently changed cell (code stored in worksheet)

```
Public reprint As String

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Const WS_RANGE As String = "B4:B4003"

On Error GoTo ws_exit:
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range(WS_RANGE)) Is Nothing Then
With Target
Let reprint = Target.Value
End With
End If

ws_exit:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It's possible for 'Target' to be more than a single cell (it could even be whole column(s)/rows(s)) so you might want to check for that in your code.  What's the trigger for updating sheet2 with the value of `reprint` ?  Should it occur as part of the `Worksheet_Change` event?

Comment: Very interesting point! The function of my workbook is for users to be able to enter in data via a userform, the information is pasted into a sheet and recalled with a "reprint" function that automatically prints the last entered data. I want the reprint function to automatically find the last cell updated, which then forms the basis for recalling this information. If they enter in multiple lines though, will this code recall all the values? ie. does this code find ALL the changes or just the most recent? The trigger for updating sheet2 is another userform :)

Comment: How you handle multiple "latest" values is something you'll need to work out, and it's difficult for me to make any suggestions without knowing more about your exact workflow/layout.  The code I posted below will only save the first value of multiple cells are updated in one operation: that might or might not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks Tim, really appreciate your patience! I ended up doing this, it's not the prettiest but works. It just holds the value I'm looking for in a cell that gets overwritten every time there's a new change. That way I only get the most recent update

`Public reprint As String

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const WS_RANGE As String = "B4:B4003"

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range(WS_RANGE))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Range("AZ4").Value = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value
    reprint = Range("AZ4").Value
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly safer version of your code - it will handle multi-cell updates and cases like changing range A4:B4 in a single update.  As written you didn't need the code to disable events (unless you left out some other code)

```
Public reprint As String

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const WS_RANGE As String = "B4:B4003"

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range(WS_RANGE))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    reprint = rng.Cells(1).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, this looks great! The final step that I need is to paste this value into another worksheet. At the moment the code is sitting in a userform and goes something like this ... Range("E10").Value = reprint. Call me a complete noob, but I can't for the life of me figure out how this works

Comment: `Range("E10").Value  = Sheet1.reprint` Should work. `reprint` is in the scope of the Sheet1 code module, so you need to include that.